# Edit a question to protect reputations with side-effect of changing meaning--why is it not allowed?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, reputation, disputed-review-audits, ethics

Recently my revision was rejected on the grounds that I changed the intent of the author of the question.

That is true and the rejection of my edit was just. Dear reader you can follow the links in the answer below to see my mistakes if you like.

Sincerely I am thankful for ***Your*** help in permitting me to learn not to change the intent of the author.

I had ***good intentions*** changing the words thinking I was ***guarding against a reputation damaging*** claim. But you all have showed me reputations are tougher than just one claim, and that the truth will emerge from the discussion.

But now you good folk who keep on editing my revisions and changing my meaning and intent are acting *double-standard-mongering-mugwumpishly*.  Furthermore the most ***recent edit that rolled-back my edit*** was incomplete because it ***failed to restore the title***.

***I have restored the word, reputation, to the title, in deference to your inputs on this.***

Comment: I don't see the statement on the question damaging someone's reputation just because OP can't get it work. Instead, if I found that the code did work, I would ask for clarification which part didn't work, because it seems OP had misunderstanding, or missing something crucial on that code. Commenting is the correct way.

Comment: thanks Andrew T.   I understand better now how StackOverflow guards against damage to reputations  because a bad question can be voted down and even closed.  So I don't need to edit, I can vote down.  FYI:   I found the code did work. Then much later, weeks, I found one case where it did not.  As I recall I clarified the situation in a comment.

Answer (score 20):

Both of your edits:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8747512
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8749151

were rightfully rejected, because they put words in the mouth of the asker. When editing, you want to make changes that improve the wording or formatting of a post while still preserving the author's intent. Your edits did not do this.

If you feel an author is making an incorrect assumption, the place to call this out is in comments, not edits. Even in academia, you don't rewrite someone else's paper to remove statements you disagree with, you write a response to it.

Comment: I accept your argument, except for the analogy to academia. The end result of the scholarly paper does not contain the erroneous and damaging statements, nor does it contain the comments that led to their removal. In Academia co-authors 'rewrite' the lead author's paper all the time. Perhaps we are not co-authors in stack exchange.  I also very much take offense to your use of the term, disagree with, because it frames this issue as if the author did not erroneously characterize the code of another, and thus ignores the ethics of persisting that offense. Ok the onus on us to read the comments.

Comment: I have to emphasize this was not about feelings or assumptions. It was about an incorrect assertion damaging to another's reputation.

Comment: Personally, I don't regard a statement of "doesn't work" as being damaging to someone's reputation. I've had plenty of people state that code of mine "didn't work" when instead they were making an incorrect assumption about what it did, and none of that has been damaging to my reputation. I've even had scientific papers that someone said this about, when they were not correctly reproducing the conditions laid out in a given experiment. An open response to those, indicating where they went wrong, still seemed to be the proper way to handle that. It can also be educational.

Comment: the reputation game is complex.

Answer (score -2):

The best way to protect reputation of person X

in a question by person Y

when you think person Y made a false claim about the work of person X

is to VOTE DOWN THE QUESTION AND COMMENT.

DO NOT CHANGE MEANING of person Y.